# How to test for exceptions thrown using xUnit, SubSpec and FakeItEasy

Tags: c#, unit-testing, bdd, xunit, fakeiteasy

I’m using xUnit, SubSpec and FakeItEasy for my unit tests.
I’ve so far created some positive unit tests like the following:

```
"Given a Options presenter"
    .Context(() =>
        presenter = new OptionsPresenter(view,
                                         A<IOptionsModel>.Ignored,
                                         service));

"with the Initialize method called to retrieve the option values"
    .Do(() => 
        presenter.Initialize());

"expect the view not to be null"
    .Observation(() =>
        Assert.NotNull(view));

"expect the view AutoSave property to be true"
    .Observation(() => Assert.True(view.AutoSave));
```

But now I want to write some negative unit tests and check that certain methods don't get  called, and an exception is thrown

e.g.

```
"Given a Options presenter"
    .Context(() =>
        presenter = new OptionsPresenter(view,
                                         A<IOptionsModel>.Ignored,
                                         service));

"with the Save method called to save the option values"
    .Do(() => 
        presenter.Save());

"expect an ValidationException to be thrown"
    .Observation(() =>
        // TODO 
     );

"expect an service.SaveOptions method not to be called"
    .Observation(() =>
        // TODO 
     );
```

I can see FakeItEasy has a MustNotHaveHappened extension method, and xUnit has an Assert.Throws method.

But how do I put it all together?

The exception I want to test for should occur when the Save method is called. So I’m guessing I should wrap an Assert.Throws method around the presenter.Save() method call, but I thought the presenter.Save method should be called in the .Do(() => ...

Can you please advise if my unit test should look like below or something else?

```
"Given a Options presenter"
    .Context(() =>    
        presenter = new OptionsPresenter(view,
                                         model,
                                         service));

"expect the Presenter.Save call to throw an Exception"
    .Observation(() =>
        Assert.Throws<FluentValidation.ValidationException>(() => presenter.Save()));

"expect the Service.SaveOptions method not to be called"
    .Observation(() =>
        A.CallTo(() => service.SaveOptions(A<IOptionsModel>.Ignored)).MustNotHaveHappened());
```

Many thanks

Comment: Not sure this might help, but did you check the documentation on SubSpec for example https://bitbucket.org/johannesrudolph/subspec/src/a35fcc8ae1f6/test/SubSpec.Tests/ContextSetupTeardownBehavior.cs                          Also these are BDD/Specification based tests not Unit Tests. You might get better audience if you include the tag BDD.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
"Given a Options presenter"
    .Context(() =>
        presenter = new OptionsPresenter(view,
                                         (IOptionsModel)null,
                                         service));

"with the Save method called to save the option values"
    .Do(() => 
        exception = Record.Exception(() => presenter.Save()));

"expect an ValidationException to be thrown"
    .Observation(() =>
        Assert.IsType<ValidationException>(exception)
     );

"expect an service.SaveOptions method not to be called"
    .Observation(() =>
        A.CallTo(() => service.SaveOptions(A<IOptionsModel>.Ignored)).MustNotHaveHappened()
     );
```

Or better still, switching SubSpec for [xBehave.net](http://nuget.org/packages/Xbehave) and introducing [FluentAssertions](http://nuget.org/packages/FluentAssertions):-

```
"Given an options presenter"
    .x(() => presenter = new OptionsPresenter(view, (IOptionsModel)null, service));

"When saving the options presenter"
    .x(() => exception = Record.Exception(() => presenter.Save()));

"Then a validation exception is thrown"
    .x(() => exception.Should().BeOfType<ValiationException>());

"And the options model must not be saved"
    .x(() => A.CallTo(() =>
        service.SaveOptions(A<IOptionsModel>.Ignored)).MustNotHaveHappened());
```

Answer (score 12):

I've not heard of FakeItEasy or SubSpec (your tests look pretty funky, so I might check these out :)). However, I do use xUnit so this may be helpful:

I use Record.Exception with Assert.ThrowsDelegate

So something like:

```
    [Fact]
    public void Test()
    {
        // Arange

        // Act
        Exception ex = Record.Exception(new Assert.ThrowsDelegate(() => { service.DoStuff(); }));

        // Assert
        Assert.IsType(typeof(<whatever exception type you are looking for>), ex);
        Assert.Equal("<whatever message text you are looking for>", ex.Message);
    }
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 5):

This is one way to do it in **FakeItEasy**.

```
Action act = () => someObject.SomeMethod(someArgument);
act.ShouldThrow<Exception>();
```

Comment: I'm getting a "Action does not contain a definition for ShouldThrow..." What reference/assembly do I need to include?

Comment: act.Should().Throw<Exception>();