# Unit test code in catch statement with a throw

Tags: c#, unit-testing, error-handling, try-catch, throws

Is there a way to test code in catch statement, the trick is the catch ends with a `throw` and this is where things go side ways. So the question is,is there a way to avoid that throw when running my Test method or maybe accomodate it on my test?

The method below just simply updates values and on catch it has a `throw`

```
public void UpdateCase(LinqToSQLModelName record, IProgress<string> statusReporter)
        {

            try
            {
                statusReporter.Report(record.Reference);
                _service.PushToService(record);
                record.ProcessedDate = DateTime.Now;
                record.StatusId = (int)Status.Processed;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                record.StatusId = (int)Status.Fail;
                record.ErrorExceptions = ex.StackTrace;
                record.ProcessedDate = DateTime.Now;
                Result = false;

                throw ex;//How do dodge this when running my test/ Accomodate it on my Test
            }
            finally
            {
                _db.SubmitChanges();
            }

        }
```

I need need to test the catch part now, test below

```
 [TestMethod()]
        public void UpdateCaseErrorTest()
        {

            var repository = new Mock<IDataContext>();
            var errorLoggerRepository = new Mock<IExceptionLogger>();
            var serviceRepository = new Mock<IServiceInterface>();
            repository.Setup(m => m.Get()).Returns(new 
            ManualWithDrawDataContext());

            repository.Setup(m => m.GetCouncilRefundRecord())
             .Returns(new LinqToSQLModelName
             {
                 refrence= "10",
                 Reason = "Reason",
                 DateCaptured = DateTime.Now,

             });

            var sut = new DataContext(repository.Object.Get(), serviceRepository.Object, errorLoggerRepository.Object);

             sut.UpdateCase(repository.Object.GetCouncilRefundRecord(), null);//This null allows me to go to the catch

             Assert.IsFalse(sut.Result);
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no way you can skip the throw statement of catch. However, you can attach the `ExpectedExceptionAttribute` over unit test method so that it indicates that an exception is expected during test method execution. You can read about `ExpectedExceptionAttribute` at [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.expectedexceptionattribute.aspx).

```
    [TestMethod()]
    [ExpectedException(typeof(Exception))]
    public void UpdateCaseErrorTest()
    {

        var repository = new Mock<IDataContext>();
        var errorLoggerRepository = new Mock<IExceptionLogger>();
        var serviceRepository = new Mock<IServiceInterface>();
        repository.Setup(m => m.Get()).Returns(new 
        ManualWithDrawDataContext());

        repository.Setup(m => m.GetCouncilRefundRecord())
         .Returns(new LinqToSQLModelName
         {
             refrence= "10",
             Reason = "Reason",
             DateCaptured = DateTime.Now,

         });

        var sut = new DataContext(repository.Object.Get(), serviceRepository.Object, errorLoggerRepository.Object);

         sut.UpdateCase(repository.Object.GetCouncilRefundRecord(), null);//This null allows me to go to the catch

         Assert.IsFalse(sut.Result);
    }
```

Also, I would suggest that instead of catching general exception, define the attribute with specific exception.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way of doing this with Record.Exception in xunit and see more below the link:

[How to test for exceptions thrown using xUnit, SubSpec and FakeItEasy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11013025/how-to-test-for-exceptions-thrown-using-xunit-subspec-and-fakeiteasy)